# Svelte looping over array inside <style> tag

Tags: svelte

is it possible to perform a #each loop inside the style tag ?
the intuitive answer would be

```
<style>
      {#each styles as s}
           .{s.name} {
               {@html s.style};
           }
      }
</style>
```

but this wrong and doesn't work.

is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally does not work. Styles have to be static at build time.

You can use a preprocessor like SASS or LESS to generate styles more easily, but you cannot pass variables from the script. See [`svelte-preprocess`](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess) for usage in components.

You could generate `<style>` elements in code and add them dynamically but you would not be able to use Svelte markup syntax.